# SQL Server 2012 full text search, can you use NEAR to match 'dave or david smith'?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, full-text-search

I have this query:

`select * from catnames where contains(name, 'NEAR((david, smith), MAX, TRUE)')`

Which matches David Smith where the terms appear in order.

I'm wondering if it's possible to check david OR dave smith in the same query. The documentation for CONTAINS and NEAR is a little confusing. I've played around with a few attempts, mostly trying to add 'OR', but no dice.

Is it possible?

(Edit: Obviously, I mean within a single CONTAINS rather than chaining both CONTAINS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an OR operator in your full text search.

`select * from catnames where contains(name, 'NEAR((david, smith), MAX, TRUE) OR NEAR((dave, smith), MAX, TRUE)')`

Comment: Ah excellent, I didn't think to put the OR on just the NEAR statement. I thought it should go inside the NEAR() eg. (NEAR(dave OR david). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the full-text-search thesaurus to indicate that "David" and "Dave" are synonyms, and therefore would not need the OR clause.  The thesaurus allows you to declare replacement terms and expansion terms.  For your case, you would use an expansion term.  The entry in the XML thesaurus file (there is one per language) would look like this:

```
<expansion>
    <sub>David</sub>
    <sub>Dave</sub>
</expansion>
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142491(v=sql.110).aspx) for more info on thesaurus files in SQL Server 2012.